# Swipe refresh wheel not vanishing even after task has completed (Android)

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I created a swipe refresh layout in my android app.
There is a ListView in the main activity fragment and when the user swipes the list view, the app fetches data from the internet to display in the listview.
My problem is that even after fetching the data (correctly), the swipe refresh wheel is not going away from the app.
Here is the code for my main fragment xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And here is the code for my Main activity fragment file (partial)

```
swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
    swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            Log.v(TAG, "Swiped!") ;
        }
    });
```

I created the refresh listener inside the onCreateView method of the Main activity fragment.
What can I do to correct it?

Comment: Its quite obvious when you finishing a executable code you have to finish or release or remove or destroy each thing related to that code which dont needed or which needs to be call at finish

Answer (score 6):

Once your task is finished call:

```
swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
```